# Eclipse editing my include paths on exit and/or launch(CDT)

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, eclipse-cdt

Using Eclipse kelper and the CDT, I add an include path manually under
Properties->GCC C++ Compiler->Includes called "../../../../XXX/YYY/Hdr"

Note this is completely relative path

When I quit eclipse and reopen the project, the include path I entered has been changed by eclipse to :
"${ProjDirPath}/../../../XXX/YYY/Hdr"

I don't want this. I want the original relative path. How do I keep this path?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem and post an answer here as a cautionary tale. The problem was that the .project and .cproject files in each of my projects were read-only. When I edited the projects in eclipse and saved the changes, they didn't get saved. Regretfully, Eclipse did not prompt or warn me in this case.

When I exited Eclipse and re-launched I got the old project files before the edits